# MySQL AND operator against same column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in sql called `TagQuestion` which has fields like `id`, `tagId`, `questionId`.

Below is the data present in the table:

```
+---------------------+
|id |tagId |QuestionId|
+---------------------+    
|2  |1     |2         |
|4  |1     |3         |
|6  |2     |3         |
+---------------------+
```

I want  questionIds from the table for which `tagId=1` as well as `tagId=2`

I was trying the query as -

```
select * from TagQuestion where (tagId=1 AND tagId=2)
```

But its not returning anything.

Can you please help me out with this

Comment: What would be your exact desired result? Just "3"?

Comment: The query return nothing because its logic is wrong. Can you name a number which satisfy number = 1 and number = 2 at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

An easy method to get such questions is to use `group by` and `having`:

```
select questionId
from TagQuestion
where tagId in (1, 2)
group by questionId
having count(distinct tagId) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Query:

```
select * from TagQuestion where tagId IN (1,2)
```

Your query is checking if `tagId=1 AND tagId=2` which is not possible for same record. For fetching records having either `tagId=1` or `tagId=2`, you need to use `IN` operator.

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

`SELECT * FROM TagQuestion WHERE tagId IN (1,2);`

your query `where (tagId = 1 and tagId = 2)` checks if `tagId` have 1 and 2 values at the time per row.. so it wont output anything is it would always be false.. another option would be to replace your `AND` to `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You claim that the column should be 1 **and** 2 at the same time - as per the laws of logic ([Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)) this is always **false** - hence it will always return 0 rows.

I suppose you intended to return rows where the column TagID contains 1 **or** 2, if that is the case, **replace** the **`AND`** in your query **by `OR`**:

`select * from TagQuestion where (tagId=1` **`OR`** `tagId=2)`